# Detect file change, offer to reload file

Tags: vim

I normally use gVim for editing, but I sometimes use vim when remotely connecting to my machine.

When I have a file opened in gVim and it has changed from outside (e.g. new updates from repository), gVim offers to reload it.

However when such a thing happens with Vim, it does nothing until you try to save the file. It just warns you that file has changed, but does not offer to reload it.

It there a setting to make Vim's behavior match gVim?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2157914/can-vim-monitor-realtime-changes-to-a-file

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This is done using an auto command called FileChangedShell. I'm too new to post links, but your best bet would be to read the autocmd part of the vim documentation (Google for that)

but the gist is to set something like the following line in your vimrc

```
:au FileChangedShell * echo "Warning: File changed on disk"
```

Comment: I don't think that's necessary, vim should warn you about the change automatically.

Comment: Though it does not, unfortunately.

Comment: Sorry Matt, it actually did, was looking at wrong file. It does display warning, but not actual prompt to reload though

Comment: Ah, ok. No worries. Hope you can find what you're looking for!

Comment: I entered that into my Konsolse vim session and it did not detect that I changed the file with kate behind vim's back. If I refocus the terminal, it does nothing. I guess the event is not fired. Any ideas?

Comment: Event "FileChangedShell" is a consequence of file change detection, not a reason. So it absolutely has no sense to have `:au FileChangedShell * somecommand` in config if you want vim to detect a file has been changed from outside. You need to trigger that event, not capture it. Matt, so your answer is misleading. I vote for Brian Carper's answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/923737/detect-file-change-offer-to-reload-file/927634#927634

Comment: Did not work for me, I am using `au CursorHold * checktime` as recommended below

Answer (score 61):

If you want to open the updated file use

```
:e
```

It should reload the open file.

Comment: Yes. But the question if how to detect the file change automatically, not how to reload it.

Answer (score 56):

As [ashcatch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/85539/ashcatch) said, the `:checktime` command will check for changes on disk and prompt you to reload.  So set Vim to run `checktime` automatically after some event.  Which event to use is up to you.  One possibility is to use `CursorHold`, which fires after you move the cursor and then let it sit still for `updatetime` milliseconds.  (Default 4 seconds.)

```
:au CursorHold * checktime
```

You could also set it on `WinEnter` or `BufWinEnter` so it changes every time you switch between buffers/windows.  If you're really paranoid you could set it on `CursorMoved` so it checks the file on disk every time you move the cursor, but that's probably overkill and may lag a bit.

See `:h checktime`, `:h updatetime`, `:h autocmd-events-abc`.

Comment: I am so bad reading vim help... I am not sure why it just numbs my mind for some reason.

Comment: Brian, vim says "No such group or event: CurshorHold * checktime "

Comment: Sorry, typo.  CurshorHold should have been Cursorhold.

Comment: Thanks ^^ I've been wonderning how to do that for quite some time now. This works nice with `set autoread` to, which will re-read the file if its contents did not change.

Comment: Didn't work for me. I tried CurshorHold and Cursorhold. I am using Windows 7 64 bits.

Comment: This works badly if you try to enter the "Command Line" (q:). See my answer for a workaround.

Comment: Use `:au CursorHold,CursorHoldI * checktime %` to only check (and reload if `autoread` is set) the current file. Note that this doesn't work if `buftype` is set, i.e. it is not a normal file (e.g. `buftype=nowrite` or is the `quickfix` or `help` buffers.)

Comment: You need to use `getcmdwintype()` (as in @DBedrenko's answer below) otherwise you get errors in the command window.

Answer (score 10):

To improve on Carper's answer:

```
" Run checktime in buffers, but avoiding the "Command Line" (q:) window
au CursorHold * if getcmdwintype() == '' | checktime | endif
```

Without this check Vim will spout errors if you try to use the "Command Line" (q:) buffer, because this buffer doesn't support the `:checktime` command. Found this out thanks to kdlv on #vim.

Comment: Looks like `getcmdwintype()` may require vim 7.4?  I seem to have it working on 7.3 using `getcmdtype()` instead.

Comment: You can use `au CursorHold,CursorHoldI * silent! checktime` to ignore errors. This will work in earlier Vim versions too.

Comment: It is also nice to use `FocusGained,CursorHold` instead of just `CursorHold` to ensure that the buffer is updated immediately after re-focussing it.

Answer (score 9):

You can manually trigger the checking with `:checktime`. gvim does this everytime it regains focus, so it is not necessary that often to do the manual checking.

I don't know if there is a different approach (like automatically checking in a certain time interval).

Comment: Why can't vim also trigger `:checktime` when it gains focus? Is this a curses program limitation?

Comment: @KFL ansi escape sequences exist for gaining/losing focus, so in theory this is doable. It depends on your specific terminal emulator if these are sent. iTerm2 does for example.

Answer (score 3):

from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48296697/4940240) (refering to an answer by [PhanHaiQuang](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2467354/phan-hai-quang) and a comment by [flukus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/407256/flukus))

One can run this oneliner from ex (whithin vim) when needed (or put each command in vimrc, for when log-files are opened.)

`:set autoread | au CursorHold * checktime | call feedkeys("lh")`

Explanation:
- **autoread**: reads the file when changed from the outside (but it doesnt work on its own, there is no internal timer or something like that. It will only read the file when vim does an action, like a command in ex `:!`
- **CursorHold * checktime**: when the cursor isn't moved by the user for the time specified in 'updatetime' (which is 4000 miliseconds by default) checktime is executed, which checks for changes from outside the file
- **call feedkeys("lh")**: the cursor is moved once, right and back left. and then nothing happens (... which means, that CursorHold is triggered, which means we have a **loop**)