# How to get notified when file is changed by another application?

Tags: vim

Before I heard about vim, I used to use gedit. I still try to make vim behave as same as gedit, this is because I have asked many questions related to vim on StackOverflow.

One feature I am missing is when any file was modified while I was working on any file on gedit by another application, a popup use to come which says `The file <file_location> changed on disk. Do you want to reload the file?` And there were two buttons named <kbd>Reload</kbd> and <kbd>Cancel</kbd> respectively.

---

#### *What I want:*

*(Please note that I am using vim, not gvim)* I want similar feature in vim. I want if any file get changed on disk, a warning message come at status bar:

```
File changed, press F9 to reload.
```

I will map my <kbd>F9</kbd> to do `:e`.

Comment: Right now it will warn you in the statusline, but only if you attempt to save new changes. And I suppose you already found out that gVim _does_ send a popup when a file changes externally

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If `autoread` is set, vim checks whether the file has been modified after each shell command (`:!`), on writing the file, and when you issue `:checktime`.  gvim in addition checks when you switch window focus to the application.

You can execute `:checktime` periodically using the recipe at http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Timer_to_execute_commands_periodically:

```
autocmd CursorHold * call Timer()
function! Timer()
    call feedkeys("f\e")
    checktime
endfunction
set updatetime=5000  " milliseconds
```

To just print a warning, set the [autocmd `FileChangedShell`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/autocmd.html#FileChangedShell) ([Detect file change, offer to reload file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/923737/detect-file-change-offer-to-reload-file)):

```
autocmd FileChangedShell * echo "File changed, press F9 to reload."
```

For Insert mode, use `CursorHoldI` (not sure about this feedkeys sequence, but it seems to work):

```
autocmd CursorHoldI * call TimerI()
function! TimerI()
    call feedkeys("\<C-R>\e")
    checktime
endfunction
```

You might have to change the `FileChangedShell` autocmd from `echo` to `echoe`, as I don't think `echo` gets printed in Insert mode.

Comment: So, how do I make vim check every 5 seconds?

Comment: Can you give full configuration?

Comment: Heyy.. I did not wanted to update automatically. I want to show warning at status bar only.

Comment: A silly question. Will doing all these give my RAM or CPU more pressure than before? If yes, how much?

Comment: You'll be waking up the CPU every 5 seconds, so that'll have a power draw.  Should be pretty insignificant, though; it doesn't need to go to disk as the OS will have the information cached, and your computer has more frequent wakeups anyway.

Comment: Some weird things are happening. File is updating automatically in normal mode *(I expected to just show warning, by the way its ok)*. The warning is not shown in insert mode, even nothing is happening when in insert mode *(I expected atleast to get notified when there is a file change)*. What do I do?

Comment: You can use `CursorHoldI` to run an autocmd in Insert mode, but it won't be safe to use the same `feedkeys` sequence.

Comment: @Santosh also if you don't want the file to update automatically, turn off `autoread`.

Comment: Can you tell me what should be feedkeys for insert mode?

Comment: What is difference between `function` and `function!`?

Comment: @Santosh `function!` overwrites an existing function.  See http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#user-functions

Answer (score 0):

Trying to force Vim into working like another editor is a pointless exercise. I've been guilty of that (with TextMate as a model) and it has been both a complete failure and an obstacle on the learning curve.

However, what you are asking — notification on external change — is the default behavior which can be reversed with `:set autoread`.

Comment: I already have autoread set. But that seem to work with gvim, not vim, as I already hinted in my question.

Comment: Hmm, I was going to tell you about `:checktime` but @ecatmur beat me to it.

Comment: **...pointless exercise.**. Maybe next time. I solved my problem this time ;)